# Why isn’t any Windows 10 Pro autologon method working?

Tags: windows-10, login, regedit, user, autologon

I have setup a Windows 10 Pro computer with local GPO and registry edits that is meant to be used only for internet browsing. So, I configured it with two local user accounts besides the main Administrator account. One that acts as an admin account (fAdmin) and another as a user account for internet browsing (fUser). Both accounts have a password.

I haven’t gotten the fUser to automatically log in even through I’ve used several methods. I keep seeing the user account name and a password box at the login page.

**Methods I’ve tried**

**Netplwiz**

In registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PasswordLess\Device

Set value DevicePasswordLessBuildVersion to 0.

Reboot.

Then inside fAdmin open Netplwiz.

Choose fuser and uncheck “Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer.”

Click OK and type password.

Restart computer and user account fuser still doesn’t login automatically.

**Registry (regedit)**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/user-profiles-and-logon/turn-on-automatic-logon

In the key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

Create or change values to:

AutoAdminLogon (string): 1

DefaultUserName (string): fuser

DefaultUserPassword: the password for fuser

LastUsedUsername (string): fuser

DefaultDomainName (string): Computer name

AutoLogonSID (string): fuser SID

Reboot.

User account fuser still doesn’t log in automatically.

AutoLogon Sysinternals from Microsoft
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon
Did not work.

**Summary**

The only way I have gotten fuser to login automatically is if I reset it’s password with netplwiz program. Is this the only way?
I’ve seen other mention that is not the best way for security reasons. So this is not an ideal solution.
Is it possible to have a local user account automatically login if it has a password?

Comment: Is the user a Microsoft account or a Local account? Also, what do you mean by reset its password, setting no password? Try out: Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options > "Use my sign in info to automatically finish setting up my device after an update or restart."

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Two local accounts. Reset account in netplwiz.
What I'm asking is if it's even possible to have a local user account automatically login if it has a password?